# URL to reference images in Magento

Tags: magento

what's the best way to reference an image from within a .phtml file in Magento. I'm trying to insert an image (sitting in the 'images' folder) into footer.phtml and

```
{{skin url='images/image.gif'}}
```

doesn't seem to work. any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're referring to the images folder in your skin folder, then you could use `Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/image.gif')`.

Answer (score 2):

> $this->getSkinUrl('images/image.gif')